# parsley.js validate form that is split into two divs

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a form that I need to validate. It runs over two Divs in a responsive layout. The form submits as one form. But I cannot get parsley.js to validate both sections.
If I put the form into one div it works but I need the two parts of the form to be next to each other and not one long continues form. [Here is a link to the form](http://oslokammermusikkfestival.no/gavekort.html)

Hope this makes sense.

What do I need to do?

Thanks, Baiji

Answer (score 0):

You have to put **all** the inputs (even if there are on two columns) inside the **same** `<form></form>` tags.

Comment: Thanks, but they are all inside the same form tag.

Comment: Ok so you have a closing `</div>` problem,  near line 93. In Chrome code inspector I see `</form>` closing before right columns. Indent your code, it would be easier to debug..

Comment: Thanks, guillaumepotier. I appreciate you taking time to look at this. If I remove the two </div> on 93. The validation works but not the columns. So I have to figure out how to solve that. Thanks for your help, though.